# Certain functions/methods not changing when built in Xcode

Tags: xcode, methods, build, compilation

I am currently working on a project which runs just fine in both the simulator and on device except for one particular method which does not update on the device or in the simulator. It seams that I can put whatever I like in it and it just runs an old version. If I change other methods in the same file they build and run with the changes. Any ideas why this is happening or what I could do to solve it?

One suggestion I heard was to start a new project and copy my code in. I would like to avoid that if possible but it looks like I might have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you need to do a clean build because Xcode does not always notice dependency changes (e.g. changes to source files).

Some people do not configure their dependencies (e.g. static/dynamic libraries) correctly. If you are using the auto-detect-dependency feature, it still has some bugs, so you may need to configure this explicitly.

FWIW, starting a new project has never been necessary for me...

Comment: I have tried doing a clean build but with no luck. With static/dynamic libraries, as far as I know they are ok but I'll do a but of checking. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ok, so the dependancies are not configured but are being auto detected correctly as far as I can tell. Besides, I'm not changing code in the framework in using (cocos2d). I was going to try doing it explicitly to see if it might help but can't figure out how it works in Xcode 4.

Comment: ok - among several other places, it is outlined here: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=14XR5zcZb2Kz2s6A4AbzB00NLkrW9bWxMMprVsUao-hY

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. I have also tried just restarting Xcode, my mac etc and deleting some cache files with no luck either. I also checked that the file is under compile sources. Plus, I can make changes to any other method in the same file and changes build just not in this one particular one.

Comment: hmm - makes me wonder if the instance is the type you expect, is `nil`, or if a selector has been mistyped. there are more obscure reasons this could happen (e.g. method swizzling).

Comment: ok, I think I've got it. I had some method names that were causing some problems. I feel a bit silly now for missing that.

Comment: *shrug* it eventually happens to everybody!